Pole structure of the photon polarisation tensor

When it comes to the photon polarisation tensor in the book of Peskin & Schroeder on page 246, it is said:

Notice that as long as $\Pi(q^2)$ is regular a $q^2=0$, the exact propagator always has a pole at $q^2=0$. In other words, the photon remains absolutely massless at all orders of perturbation theory.


However, the ($\alpha$ leading order) approximation of $\Pi(q^2)$: $\Pi_2(q^2)$ is divergent at $q^2=0$ as written between equation (7.90) and (7.91):
$$\Pi_2(0) = -\frac{2\alpha}{3\pi \epsilon} \stackrel{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}{\rightarrow} \infty.\tag{p.252}$$


How do these 2 statements fit together?

Is $\epsilon$ a regularization parameter? The statement "$\Pi(q^2)$ is regular at $q^2=0$" only applies to the renormalized quantity which should be finite.


On one hand, $\Pi^{\mu\nu}(q)=(q^2g^{\mu\nu}-q^{\mu}q^{\nu})\Pi_2(q^2)$ in eqs. (7.72)-(7.75) is the renormalized 1PI photon vacuum polarization/self-energy.

On the other hand, $\Pi^{\mu\nu}(q)=(q^2g^{\mu\nu}-q^{\mu}q^{\nu})\Pi_2(q^2)$ in eqs. (7.71), (7.78), (7.79) & (7.90) is the divergent electron 1-loop contribution to the photon vacuum polarization/self-energy.


